# How can I make a MYSQL view update after a trigger causes an insert on table used in view

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, view

I have a MYSQL table that I insert into based on a trigger and I have a view that uses this table (and joins on others). When my trigger fires and inserts a new row it shows up fine in the table but the view does not update. Is there a way I can get the view to update or is this a limitation of triggers?

Note: regular inserts into the table update the view just fine, only inserts from a trigger are missing from the view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: views don't need to be 'updated', however materialized views do. But, MySQL does not support materialized views. This leads me to believe you're not actually talking about a view, rather a table that was once populated by a query?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia by view I mean what is created when you run `create or replace view some_name as select ...` as referenced here: [mysql view doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-syntax.html).

I'm confused about it too because I thought views should not need updating either but in this case I think it may be the result of the trigger because regular inserts into the table the view uses update the view just fine.

Comment: what happens when you execute the select statement inside that view against the database? Does it return the row? If not then inner joins with other tables are probably eliminating it from the result set, which is why the view would not show it (as it's the same as the query). In that case, maybe the trigger should be inserting additional things into other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the joins I used to make the view - I had inner joins on fields that were only NULL during inserts from the trigger. I switched them to left joins and now the view updates fine regardless of whether the insert is from a trigger or not.

Also, @PM-77-1's  answer is correct but in this case I was not altering any columns, just inserting new rows of data.

Comment: Go ahead and accept your own answer. Mine was indeed off-topic for this particular discussion.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) (with my emphasis):

> The view **definition** is “frozen” at creation time, so changes to the
>   underlying tables afterward do not affect the view definition. For
>   example, if a view is defined as SELECT * on a table, **new columns
>   added to the table later do not become part of the view**.

So your trigger code should include `ALTER VIEW` statement (if you are absolutely certain that the view exists) or `CREATE OR REPLACE` (if you are not).

For additional information on `MySQL views` (not related to the question at hand) see [`Restrictions on Views`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html).

Comment: This is something new that I learnt. I don't think the same concept of "frozen" applies in Oracle though.

Comment: incorrect. Views are "compiled" are the point of creating them. The columns are then static until the view is altered by "create or replace". You could add dozens of fields to the tables involved and they will not appear magically in your views. Using `select *` is not a guarantee of "automatically add fields". Just image creating a view of an employee table, then later someone add '`is_redundant` to the table. Should that automatically appear in all views of the employee table? (No!)

Comment: @Used_By_Already - I'm confused. What exactly is "*incorrect*"? You just reiterated what my answer stated. I see no contradiction whatsoever. As far as `SELECT *` is concerned it was used just to clarify the point by the authors of MySQL docs.

Comment: sorry; the reference to `I don't think the same concept of "frozen" applies in Oracle though` is incorrect. It does apply to an Oracle view - although the term isn't formally used. What I was saying is that Oracle's  views also are "compiled" at point of creation/update and don't automatically include new columns. That was all - poorly expressed maybe. sorry.